# How do I query the activities on the stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity that edits a contact item. As well as being invoked by navigation within the app, I have a home screen shortcut to the EditItem activity.

My problem is that potentially a user could be editing a contact, forget that he was doing so, and re-edit the contact via the shortcut, ie there could be two EditItem activities on the stack. If this happens, edits from one will clobber the other.

How do I detect and/or avoid this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mark your edit activity as a "singleTask" in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".EditActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

You can read up on the `launchMode` mode in the [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). To quote it,

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes
>   the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already
>   exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a
>   call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

For instance, I've used this mode for a map activity that could cause cycles in the activity stack. To avoid a user doing activity A -> B -> C -> B -> C and then having to press Back through all of them, I made activity C a "singleTask". That way the user only ever had to press Back once from activity B to reach activity A.